# Condition for $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:{\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R}$. Is there a courterexample for the following equality or is it always true?

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

What I think is that one might need a non-continuous function since this is always true for a continuous function. Would $1_{\Bbb Q}$ work? Are there any other counterexamples?

Comment: $1_\mathbb{Q}$ works in the sense that the RHS limit exists and the LHS limit does not.  There are plenty of other counterexamples in this sense (_e.g._ the one in my answer.)

Comment: What $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ means? Thanks.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov: It is the indicator function for the rational numbers, i.e. $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, even for a function which is discontinuous at only one point, this need not be true. For example: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(\pi/x)&:x\neq0\\ 0&:x=0\end{cases}.$$ This equals $0$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ as $\pi/(1/n)=n\pi$ but the limit as $x\to0$ does not exist. However, if the function is continuous, then yes, the limits will be equal.

Thus, as you can see, the only way to guarantee the limits are equal is if $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$ exists.

Comment: What does "subsequence of $x \to 0$" mean?

Comment: @TrevorWilson: When considering $x\to0$, it's equivalent to considering all possible sequences converging to $0$; this is just one of those sequences.

Comment: I know that sequential continuity is equivalent to continuity in $\mathbb{R}$, I'm just questioning your notation. To me the phrase "$x \to 0$" does not denote a sequence, so I don't know what a subsequence of it would be.

Comment: Nice example! +1

Comment: Nice function, the beautiful one on Earth +1

Answer (score 5):

If the left hand side limit exists, then both limits exist and are equal.  However, it is possible for the right hand side limit to exist and the left hand side limit not to exist (in which case $f$ must be discontinuous.) For example, let $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: I'm assuming the limit on the right hand side is taken over $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by the way.

Comment: @blf Then the limit on the RHS would be more commonly written as $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$, and the answer is the same (but you would need a different counterexample, like the indicator function for $[0,\infty)$.)